# Passing arguments to javascript file, how does it work?

Tags: javascript

From the tutorial [ScriptJSONOptions](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#ScriptJSONOptions) of FirebugLite page, I found the below:

---

## Script JSON options

It is possible to set options using a JSON object inside the linked script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js">
{
    overrideConsole: false,
    startInNewWindow: true,
    startOpened: true,
    enableTrace: true
}
</script>
```

---

It means that we can pass the arguments to javascript file.
But I don't know how does it work?

#### Update:

> My question is how to get the arguments inside the js file?

#### P/S:

I also looked into code, but I could not find the code is implemented this feature.

Comment: That is not a JSON object. JSON objects have quotes around the key names.

Comment: Yes, but my question is how to get the arguments in js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be achieved by finding the correct "script" dom node and then eval() its text content. In jQuery

```
 eval("var mySettings = " + jQuery("script[src*='firebug']").text() );
```

Comment: Aha, so amazing, I will try and then tell you.

Comment: Indeed this is what is done in the firebug lite script: `var innerOptions=FBL.trim(script.innerHTML); if(innerOptions){var innerOptionsObject=eval("("+innerOptions+")");`